# Is there a way to stop browser console from being too chatty in blazor server app?

Tags: blazor-server-side

We have an app in currently under development in a UAT environment. It's Blazor server app in dotnet6.
security team is complaining that they can see errors in the browser console when they invoke an imaginary method. They do something like DotNet.invokemethod('imaginaryFct',....
Is there a way to block that?

Comment: Security team should consern test uat and production. Dev environment should not contain production data and is for development

Comment: I agree however that is not the center of my question.

Comment: I understand that is fair enough, but honestly, still you need to talk to the security team and ask which value this brings to the business, but still hope someone can answer the question.

Comment: In the meantime I still need help and possible answer-s to my question...

Comment: I have edited my question to make things clearer.